# Will iphone 5.1 deployment target reach all iphones upon release of ios 6?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iphone app development and am wondering which deployment target to use (as ios 6 approaches). My app is simple (http web service interaction, map) and my natural inclination is to target 3.1 to maximize potential use. However, I understand that ios 6 will soon be available to all iphones and I presume it will be widely adopted.

So, if I target 5.1 today, will my app be available to most, if not all, iphone users once ios 6 is released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 5.1.1 as deployment target if it is available to your menu.. if not 5.1 is best for your needs for now.

This way all (Who have not updated to IOS 6) can use your app...

Best luck for app development.

Comment: I am confused about which phones use which ios. My neighbour has an iphone 3GS. Presumably she could not use an app targeting 5.1 today. Will she get ios6 for free and then be able to use a 5.1 app?

Comment: If she isn't using at least 5.1 it's because she didn't upgrade the OS. The iPhone 3GS supports all OSes from 3.x up to and including 6.0.

Comment: Great, that explains what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, requiring a minimum of 5.1 is a bit bold in my opinion, but that depends on your app. It is customary to support the current version and the previous major release.

If you want to expand your target, you may considering going back to 4.3 or even all the way down to 4.0. But 3.x is practically obsolete. but:

**Warning:** Don't target a version you can not test on device. If you don't have a device running 4.0, testing your app only on the 4.0 simulator is not recommended (although *perhaps* it is OK. No assurance).

The iPhone 3G can run up to iOS 4.2.

All other phones and iPads can run the latest OS (5.1.1)

Not sure about iPod Touch devices but 3rd (and 4th) gen. should run iOS 5.

Comment: I am fairly confident I do not require any 5.1 functionality but I was hoping to take advantage of ARC. Your answer suggests that I will limit my potential takers by using 5.1. Is this because there are still 3G users (and other users who have not upgraded). Are there any stats about how many users cannot use 5.1?

Comment: Ok, I found this link which exactly supports your response to target 4.x today. But maybe I can presume that ios 6 will be available about the time I complete my app and so maybe I should target 5.1. http://pxldot.com/18754186750

Comment: You CAN use ARC even when targeting 4.0 devices(as long as your Xcode version is new enough): ARC is 99% a compile-time technology. But there is a catch: you can not use `weak` references before iOS 5: Must use `unsafe_unretained` instead. The difference is, they don't auto-zero on deallocation of the pointed object, so if you mess up it might give rise to a Zombie (a.k.a. dangling pointer)

Comment: There ARE statistics taken by individual developers, but that only tells you the OS usage of _their_ users (not the general population). There was this guy (son't remember his name right now) a couple of months ago who reported 80+% of his users in iOS 5.x.

Comment: I downloaded Xcode a few days ago. So I think I will target 4.2 and use ARC (without `weak`). Perfect.

Comment: Great. If your app starts to crash, you can't find why and Xcode just points to UIApplicationMain(), google for 'NSZombieEnabled'.